# C language: i dont understand why it works

Tags: c

Does someone knows what happens when a `char` is returned when `int` is expected?

```
char testunc1(char a)
{
    return a;
}

void main()
{

    int x1;
    x1 = testfunc1(7);
    printf("%d\n",x1);
}
```

Comment: You will get the answer as 7. In the testfunc1 the int will be converted to char and in the main function , the char will be promoted back to int , if u want to print the  charecter  the use  printf("%c \n",x1);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `char` is *implicitly converted* to an `int`.

In section **6.5.16.1** paragraph 2 of the C99 standard:

> In *simple assignment* (`=`), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the
>   assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left
>   operand.

The type of an *assignment expression* is defined in section **6.5.16** paragraph 3:

> The type of an assignment expression is the type of the left operand unless the
>   left operand has qualified type, in which case it is the unqualified version of the type of
>   the left operand.

Since the variable is of type `int`, the returned `char` value is converted to type `int` as specified in section **6.5.16.1** of the C99 standard.

In this case, the value `7` can be fully represented by an `int`, so no loss of precision occurs as the `7` is stored in your `int` variable.

Comment: *Since the variable is of type int, the returned char value is promoted to type int following the type* There is no integer promotion in the assignment of `testfunc1` to `x1`. The right operand of the assignment operator is converted to the type of the left operand, here from `char` to `int`, but this does not occur as a part of the `6.3.1.1` integer promotions.

Comment: @ouah Yes, I believe you are correct; `6.3.1.1` covers integer promotions when evaluating expressions, not the resulting type of an assignment. I'll update the answer to quote the correct section of the standard regarding the conversion to the left operand type.

Answer (score 4):

When the function is called `int` is implicitly cast to `char`. As `char` can fit values up to 127, this works just fine. Later the result returned from the function is cast back to `int`, which of course again works as `int` fits all values that can fit in `char`.

Answer (score 2):

There is an implicit conversion between all arithmetic types in C. So here the `int` value `7` is implicitly converted to `char` when passed to the `testunc1` function. Same when `testfunc1` return value is assigned to `x1` (the `char` return value is converted to `int`).